# Why is vertical alignment of table text inconsistent and how do I fix it?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

The following code produces different vertical alignment for cells in the second and third rows (top aligned vs. centered). Top aligned is the desired result. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
    \textbf{Field 1} & \multicolumn{3}{p{10cm}|}{The label for Field 1 is aligned to the top of its cell, even though it is more than one line high due to this cell extending to multiple lines.} \\ \hline
    \textbf{Field 2} & Data for field 2 & \textbf{Field 3} & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} List of \\ Items for \\ Third field \end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Broken table]

Comment: p{} puts the baseline at the top (first baseline).  Tabular[c] (default) puts the baseline at the center.  Use `\begin{tabular}[t]...`

Comment: Alternatively, use an m{} column from the array package, or put a `\parbox[c]` into an l column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    \hline
    \textbf{Field 1}&
    
    \multicolumn{3}{p{10cm}|}{The label for Field 1 is aligned to the
      top of its cell, even though it is more than one line high due
      to this cell extending to multiple lines.}\\

    \hline

    \textbf{Field 2}&Data for field 2&\textbf{Field 3}&
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} List of\\
      Items for\\
      Third field
    \end{tabular}
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. Thanks! It is confusing to me, though, that the alignment of the nested tabular environment effects alignment of other cells in that row. Why is it wrong to expect that the `[t]` option should only affect the contents of the nested environemnt?

Comment: @Kerry, [t] specifies the vertical position of the table relative to the baseline of the surrounding text.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I simplified your code with the `makecell` package, and used the `m` column type in the place of `p`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
    \textbf{Field 1} & \multicolumn{3}{m{10cm}|}{The label for Field 1 is aligned to the top of its cell, even though it is more than one line high due to this cell extending to multiple lines.} \\ \hline
    \textbf{Field 2} & Data for field 2 & \textbf{Field 3} & \makecell[l]{List of \\ Items for \\ Third field } \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]